# Upload file using HTML5 FormData not working for IE10 Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, upload, internet-explorer-10

I have simple script to upload file using HTML5 FormData, It's working fine on most HTML5 supported browsers (I tested against Chrome, FireFox, Opera and **IE10 Metro**). The only browser that not working is on **IE10 Desktop**, the problem is file never been uploaded, on server side `Request.Files.Count` always zero.

Any idea why, or this is just IE10 Desktop bug?

Here's the scripts:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple="true"/>
<button type="button" id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
<div>
    <span>Status: </span> <strong id="status"></strong>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var files = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#fileInput').change(function (e) {
            // Add all selected files to 'files' array

            $.each(e.target.files, function(i, item) {
                files.push(item);
            });
        });


        $('#uploadButton').click(function () {

            // Put files to FormData
            var formData = new FormData();
            $.each(files, function(i, item) {
                formData.append('X-FILE-' + i, item);
            });

            // Send FormData to server
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/upload',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "YES") {
                        $('#status').text("File Uploaded");
                    } else {
                        $('#status').text("File NOT Uploaded");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's the server side code to capture '/home/upload' action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var success = Request.Files.Count > 0;
    return Content(success ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

I also pushed my code on my public repository at Github on https://github.com/budiadiono/IE10VSHtml5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have seen answers that require you to run IE10 in IE9 mode. That's not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is bug from IE 10 Desktop. Demo from Telerik http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx not working too on IE 10 Desktop, but working fine on IE 10 Metro.

To be more spesific here's the IE 10 Desktop version:

```
Version: 10.0.9200.16540
Update Versions: 10.0.4 (KB2817183)
Product ID: 00150-20000-00003-AA459
```

Comment: #Adiono hello dude right now i am facing same issue but for IE11, any words ?